# why the property 'sampleFile' is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug, multer

i'm trying to upload files to my server and store them in the "upload" file.
i followed many tutorials but i get the same error
i'm using Body-Parser

and this is the architecture of my project : [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CioVS.jpg)

Here is my /upload route Nodejs code

```js
const express = require('express');
const route = express.Router();
const multer  = require('multer');
//const upload = multer({ dest: 'upload/' });





var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, '../upload')
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now()+".jpg")
  }
})

var upload = multer({ storage: storage }).single('sampleFile')





//route.use(upload());
route.get("/upload",(req,res,next)=>{
  res.render("siteshs/upload");
});

route.post('/upload', function (req, res,next) {
  upload(req, res, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      // An error occurred when uploading
      return
    }
    console.log(req.files.sampleFile);
    // Everything went fine
  })
})
module.exports = route
```

**My PUG Code**

```
extends ../layout

block content
  form(method="post", action="/siteshs/upload")
    .form-group
      label  choisissez votre fichier excel
      input.form-control(type='file', name='sampleFile')
    .form-group
      input.form-control(type="submit", value="envoyer")
```

Comment: If you're using `single` it'll be in `req.file` not `req.files`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your multer initialization**

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, './')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.originalname);
    }
});
var upload = multer({
    storage: storage
});
```

**Handle Post Request:**

```
router.post('/todo',upload.any(),function(req,res){
    var path = req.files[0].path;
    var imageName = req.files[0].originalname;
    var imagepath = {};
    imagepath['path'] = path;
    imagepath['originalname'] = imageName;
    console.log(imagepath)
})
```

**Frontend Code:**

```
form.form-signin(action='/todo', method='post', enctype='multipart/form-data')

  textarea#tdesc.form-control(rows='5', name='tdesc')
  br
  input.form-control(type='file', name='path')
  br
  button.btn.btn-lg.btn-default.btn-block(type='submit') Add Task
```

While working with multer and file upload you have to give `enctype='multipart/form-data'` in your `form` tag.

You have to also initialize the proper location to store the image and make that path static in your `app.js` something like `app.use(express.static('./'));`

Comment: thanks for your answer Sir

But it still gives me the same error:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined

Comment: @FahdAddi  include path `const path = require('path')`